# Error with pls function in MixOmics package

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `pls` function in the [mixOmics package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixOmics/index.html).

The code I have is the following:

```
a = rnorm(100)
X = cbind(1, a, a^2, a^3)
Y = rnorm(100)
pls(X,Y)
```

When I run it, I get the following error message:

```
In pls(X, Y) : Zero- or near-zero variance predictors. 
  Reset predictors matrix to not near-zero variance predictors.
  See $nzv for problematic predictors.
```

But I don't understand where is the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you that one of your input variables (or column) in `X` has zero or very little variance.

Here, the problem is simply that your `X` in `pls(X,Y)` contains a column with constant values, so that the variance of this variable is exactly zero.

If you remove this column from your data, the pls will work ;)

```
X = X[,-1]
pls(X,Y)
```